# How to use an array in a for of loop?

Tags: javascript, for-loop

We normally have this code

```
var array1 = ['a','b','c'];
for (const [i, value] of array1.entries()) {
   console.log(i, value);
}
```

Works great but I want `[i, value]` to be dynamic.

```
var array1 = ['a','b','c'];
var keys = ['smith', 'bob']
for ( keys of array1.entries()) {
   console.log(smith, bob);
}
```

It does work if I console `keys[0]` but is there a way to get the value as keys (without `indexOf` trick)

Edit:

I'm playing around trying to replicate the basics of vuejs. I'm trying to get the dynamic variables from here: `<li v-v-for="todo,i in todos" >`

So I split that in `[let key = 'todo,i', 'todos']` and my thinking was `for( key[0] of this.data[key[1]) )`

(not using vuejs library at all)

Comment: Why do you want the variable names to be dynamic? Whatever you call them, they'll still be a key/value pair.

Comment: _"without indexOf trick"_. What `indexOf` trick?

Comment: @NicholasTower this might be a bad way of trying to replicate the `v-for` attribute from vuejs but now that I hit this wall I am interested if it can be done. Basically, I'm trying to say "it doesn't matter, I just want to know" in a polite way :)

Comment: @relidon the reason i want clarification is that this seems like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/). You have some problem X that you want to solve, and you think that dynamically assigning variable names (Y) is the way to do it, so you ask us about Y. To the rest of us, we're scratching our heads trying to figure out why you want to do Y. I can come up with hacky approaches with `eval` that would do Y, but they are almost certainly not the correct advice to give you.

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I thought it could be done with `indexOf` but I don't think it can. Sorry for any misleading

Comment: @NicholasTower As I wrote the above code I knew I might be going in the wrong direction but then I asked this simply to see if it can be done - not to copy/past in my work just to see if iy's doable. I'd love to see the hacky approach, simply to diminish my curiosity. It will save me google time

Comment: @NicholasTower I'm trying to replicate the basics of vuesj. I'm here `<li v-v-for="todo,i in todos" >` So I split that in `[let key = 'todo,i', 'todos']` and my thinking was `for( key[0] of this.data[key[1]) )`

Comment: Questions of creating dynamically named variables come up quite a bit here, but they are (almost?) always based on a misguided idea. In your example, you use the names `smith` and  `bob` in the loop, which means you *know* the names in the loop. If you know the names in the loop, why can't you define the names with `for ( let [smith, bob] of array1.entries())`. If those names might change, then the use of `smith` and `bob` in the loop will be errors. There's really no good way to do this, because there's no good reason to do it.

Comment: @MarkMeyer I used the names as a way of telling you what I was trying to get. Can you please see the edits to my question and could you tell me whether I'm completely of track - Thanks Mark

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what you mean by dynamic, but perhaps a simple JavaScript object could work for mapping a key-value pair?

```
var values = {'smith': 'a', 'bob': 'b'};
for (var key in values) {
  console.log(values[key]); //outputs all values in object
  console.log(values['smith']); //outputs 'a'
}
```

Comment: nope, that's not it `array1` and `keys` aren't linked.  Just trying to figure out if I can use the values from `keys` array as actual keys

Comment: Oh I see now. Well it would seem that `indexOf` would be the best solution then, but there may be another way